# Workaround for possible bug in Callout

Tags: plotting, labeling

When I use a background in a Callout for example `ListPlot[{Callout[{1, 1}, "This is a long Callout",  Background -> Black]}]` the background only covers a part of the Callout, see the picture below. Is there any workaround for this?

[image]

---

"12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYHBP.png I am on Mma 12.2 Windows 7. Let's wait for more responses from Linux/Mac users.

Comment: This behavior does not happen to me on Mathamatica 13.0.1 for MacOS. The black background indeed covers the whole background for me.